# Firmware Bug: disabling VPD access (can't determine size of non-standard VPD format)

Tags: kernel, kali-linux

I am using kali 2018.2
I am getting the error in `dmesg` :

```
[    0.388371] pci 0000:04:00.0: [Firmware Bug]: disabling VPD access (can't determine size of non-standard VPD format)
```

Earlier I was getting error on bootup firmware error
So I referred to another thread on this site where it was solved by copying `regulatory.db` and `regulatory.db.p7s` in lib/firmware. I rebooted and run `dmesg` command  and I found this message in place of earlier. I don't know if it was present earlier or not. It's not in red colour but still it is a bug.

How can I remove it.

Comment: Kali is notorius for problems with drivers. Read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), and unless you want Kali on an USB stick for professional pentesting (unlikely), switch to some other distro. Just as if by magic, most of your driver problems will be gone.

Comment: Is it booting or not? That message is supposed to be only an warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Welcome. Please run `apt update && apt dist-upgrade` reboot then check : `dmesg | grep VPD`.

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat has something similar to this bug in their knowledge base titled: [kernel: pci 0000:03:00.0: [Firmware Bug]: VPD access disabled](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3077141).

The remediation on this is to do the following things.

- update the kernel to the latest available
- update firmware on whatever hardware you're using
- disable any effected hardware by blacklisting it

That last bullet is mentioned in detail in that same KB article.

> ```
>     PCI: Prevent VPD access for buggy devices
>
>     On some devices, reading or writing VPD causes a system panic.
>     This can be easily reproduced by running "lspci -vvv" or
>     "cat /sys/bus/devices/XX../vpd".
>
>     Blacklist these devices so we don't access VPD data at all.
> ```

To blacklist a particular device you can read this ArchLinux Wiki page on how to accomplish this - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Blacklisting.